# How can I make the v-slot in v-data-table as responsive as the table itself?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have used the v-data-table slots such as the body.prepend and body and footer. They work fine but the issue I have is they are not responsive for small and extra small screens. In this example I am using v-slot:body.prepend={headers}
Sample code is here

```
<template v-if="isEnabled('body.prepend')" v-slot:body.prepend="{ headers }">
          <tr>
            <td class="heading">Most constant price</td>
            <td class="text-right">750</td>
            <td class="text-right">750</td>
            <td class="text-right">750</td>
            <td class="text-right">750</td>
            <td class="text-right">750</td>
            <td class="text-right">750</td>
            <td class="text-right">750</td>
            <td class="text-right">800</td>
            <td class="text-right">800</td>
            <td class="text-right">800</td>
            <td class="text-right">800</td>
            <td class="text-right">800</td>
            <td class="text-right">800</td>
            <td class="text-right">800</td>
            <td class="text-right">800</td>
            <td class="text-right">800</td>
            <td class="text-right"></td>
            <td class="text-right"></td>
          </tr>
        </template>
```

Here is a code pen example https://codepen.io/anjayluh/pen/zYOePVg?editors=1010

This is how I expect the data to appear on small screens versus how it is appearing with the use of slots.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please read about how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will make things easier for those trying to help you and increase your chances of quickly getting a solution to your problem.

Comment: can you share some code ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/Jayesh_v/pen/xmModE this might help you.

Comment: Thanks @MohsinAmjad but that example slot is not overriding the defaults as the v-slot prepend or v-slot body behave